# How to prevent a onClick on a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple dialog with these simple uses cases:

- when a user click the black background, user should close the dialog (now just window.alert)
- when a user click the button in the white div, user should perform that action

My problem: when user click any point in the white div, the function is fired, when instead I want all the white div are to do not respond on click.

Any ideas how to fix it?
CSS or JS solution appreciate

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent')
const child = document.getElementById('child')
const button = document.getElementById('button')

parent.addEventListener('click', () => window.alert('close'))

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.stopPropagation()
window.alert('do something else')}
)
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div id="child" class="child">
    some content
    <button id="button">do something else</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example, `parent` and `child` are the same object. Both do `document.getElementById('parent')`.

Comment: sorry a mistake I am going to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation):

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  console.clear();
  // only do something if the origin clicked
  // is #parent or #button
  if (origin.id === "parent") {
    return console.log('close');
  }
  if (origin.id === "button") {
    return console.log("something else");
  }
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div id="child" class="child">
    some content
    <button id="button">do something else</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Events "bubble up". So assuming that you meant to say

```
const child = document.getElementById('child')
```

you could just cancel the bubbling.

```
child.addEventListener('click', e => e.stopPropagation())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this code

```
child.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

```js
const parent = document.getElementById('parent')
const child = document.getElementById('child')
const button = document.getElementById('button')

parent.addEventListener('click', () => window.alert('close'))

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.stopPropagation()
window.alert('do something else')}
)

child.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <div id="child" class="child">
    some content
    <button id="button">do something else</button>
  </div>
</div>
```